# Find the Limits of complex number

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

Find the limit if any of

$$ { \lim_{z \rightarrow 3-4i}} \frac{(\bar z-3-4i)^4}{| z-3+4i|^4}$$

I have no idea how to start this question. Can anyone give a hint? Should i use L'hopital's Rule?

Comment: What do you get if you just plug in $z=3-4i$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson there was a slight typo in the question. Sorry for the confusion. I get 0/0 if i replace it on the function

Comment: Can you do the slightly simpler problem$$\lim_{z\to0} \frac{\bar z^4}{|z|^4}?$$

Comment: @GregMartin lim does not exist since lim along x axis is 1 and lim along x=y is -1. Am I correct?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

Let $z = 3 - 4i + re^{i\theta}$.
How does the expression simplify?

Now you need to take the limit as $r \to 0$ (and $\theta$ will possibly vary as $r \to 0$.)

Answer (score 3):

An idea what will probably make things a little clearer. Put $\;w:=3-4i\;$, so you want the limit (observe we'll use the basic equality $\;h\overline h=|h|^2\;,\;\;h\in\Bbb C$)

$$\lim_{z\to w}\frac{(\overline z-\overline w)^4}{|z-w|^4}=\lim_{z\to w}\frac{\overline{(z- w)}^4}{|z-w|^4}=\lim_{z\to w}\frac{\overline{(z- w)}^4}{(z-w)^2\overline{(z-w)^2}}=$$

$$=\lim_{z\to w}\frac{\overline{(z- w)}^2}{{(z-w)^2}}=\lim_{z\to w}\left(\frac{\overline{z-w}}{z-w}\right)^2$$

Finally, it might help to consider simply

$$\lim_{t\to0}\;\frac{\overline t}{t}\;\;\;...\;\;\text{Can you see why the limit doesn't exist?}$$

Comment: I get it now! Thanks to you and GregMartin